# Symfony2 & AJAX - How to integrate an AJAX call with the toggleClass() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I have a list of `News` objects. Every news has a `startDate` and an `expireDate`. Also, every news has a `state` property. 
If the `expireDate` is `< date('now)` then `state` is set to 0. `state` is set to 1 when `expireDate > date('now)`.

When I render the list, for the news with `state == 1` I have a toggle switch (On & Off) to activate or deactivate the news (`state == 1` or `state == 0` respectively). I can't get the toggle work properly.

This is my html for the buttons and my jQuery function that gives the `active` class to the button the user clicks:

```
    //news.html.twig
    {% if news.state == 1 %}
    <div class="btn-group btn-toggle">
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-primary active">On</button>
        <button class="btn btn-xs btn-default ">Off</button>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('.btn-toggle').click(function() {
          $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('active');  

          if ($(this).find('.btn-primary').length > 0) {
              $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-primary');
          }

          $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('btn-default');
      });
    </script>
```

I need to integrate here the `$.post` call to set the `state` for the news when the user clicks the button.
I have in mind something like this:

```
$.post('{{ path('set_news_state') }}', {id: 'news.id'}, function(response) {
    if (response.code == 100 && response.success){
        //do something
    }
}, "json");
```

These would be my controller:

```
/**
* @Route("/setNewsState/{id}", name = "set_news_state")
* @Method("POST")
**/
public function setNewsOn(Request $request, $id) {
    if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {         
        return new JsonResponse(array('data' => 'this is a json response'));
    }

    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:News');
    $news = $repository->findOneById($id);
    if ($news->getState() == 0) {
        $news->setState(1);
    } else {
        $news->setState(0);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($news);
    $em->flush();

    return new Response();
}
```

How can I integrate the `$.post` call in my already working jQuery function?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any link between `news.id` and `btn-toggle` button?

Comment: @Satpal No, there is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but it's even simpler than what you have. If you POST to the correct URL, you can get the New's entity's ID from the route parameter.

```
// news.html.twig
// You can supply a second argument to path() to fill in the route params.
$.post("{{ path('set_news_state', {'id': news.id}) }}").done(function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'ok') {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Then in your controller

```
/**
* @Route("/setNewsState/{id}", name="set_news_state")
* @Method("POST")
**/
public function setNewsOn($id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $news= $em->find('AppBundle:News', $id);

    if ($news->getState() == 0) {
        $news->setState(1);
    } else {
        $news->setState(0);
    }
    $em->persist($news);
    $em->flush();

    return new JsonResponse(array(
        'status' => 'ok'
    ));
}
```

### Last thing,

`$news = $repository->findOneById($id);` is unnecessary because `find()` searches for ID by default (well, not really, it searches for the primary key by default, but that's almost always going to be ID).

`news = $repository->find($id);` is the same, but cleaner.

Comment: I found that the main problem was with generating the route. I solved using FOSJsRoutingBundle. Your answer helped a lot too! Thanks for your time!